# My Java code is running but it is not giving any result

Tags: java, debugging

package com.company;

public class Main {

```
public static int add(int x, int y) {

    return x + y;

}

/**
 * public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
 *    int m = 0;
 *     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
 *         m = add(m, y);
 *    }
 */

public static void main(String [] args){

    add(0,2);


}
```

}

I want to:

Know the result for the addition of x + y and display it in screen. I have passed values for x and y in void main. Kindly Tell me how to know result. Thank You.

Comment: *"How to fix it?"* Add a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. See [The Java™ Tutorials - The `main` Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)

Comment: There is no `main` method defined...

Comment: You have a class called `Main`, but not a [`main()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) method.

Comment: No, there is no main method defined. The main method needs to be written as follows (which is stated by your error message): `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`.

Comment: Why don't you simply do what the error message is telling you to do? If you already have the `main` method, could you add to the code in your question, please?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `main` **method**. It does not matter what your class is called; it could be `MyMain`, or `CoolTest`, or any valid identifier. What matters is that you have a method with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Your code
}
```

Whatever you put into this method will be the code run when you run this class.

Without a `main` method, the code would be ambiguous; the JVM *would have no way of knowing which method to run*. The `main` method is the most common way of providing Java with an entry point into your code, telling it where to begin (there are other ways, but they are more complicated and probably not relevant to you at this point as a beginner). After all, what would it even mean to run your application? Should `add` be called, or `multiply`? And what values *should be added or multiplied*? The `main` method should hold the answer.

Comment: Correction, it will be what you run when you start this main method, you can have a main method in all classes

Comment: When I rewrite the code like below:

package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public static int add ( int x, int y){
            return x + y;
        }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            m = add(m, y);
        }
        return m;
    }
}

}

Comment: @Mikenno true, will fix

Comment: Well in standart java that is true, there is other ways to start code such as modules, that don't use this specific main method signature ... just to keep it fully clean :), just as a hint modules use run time containers and start/stop functions

Comment: @ostrichofevilWhen I rewrite the code like below: I'm getting lot of run time errors'.

package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public static int add ( int x, int y){
            return x + y;
        }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        int m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            m = add(m, y);
        }
        return m;
    }
}

}

Comment: Because you can't just shove methods inside other methods like that.  You need to work out what you want your `main` method to do.  Your `add` and `multiply` methods live _outside_ `main`, not inside.

Comment: @DarmeshS Defining methods is different from calling them. What you're doing is defining the method `add`: saying what it does. What you want to do is *define* `add` outside of your `main` method, and *call* it inside as follows: `add(1,3)` (replace 1 and 3 with whatever numbers you want.) Note that this code will have no apparent results; you're adding two numbers and doing nothing with the results. To print out the results, use `System.out.println(add(1,3));`

Comment: @ostrichofevil Thank You. I will try as You said in latest comment.

Comment: I'm new user to stackoverflow.com. This is my first question. I'm little sad because this question got -8. I have posted this question genuinely to know the correct code to run the program. But it got down votes. It is really bad My question has received -8 down votes. Whoever down voted kindly undo it so there is no downvotes for this question. Thank You.

Comment: @Andreas,@VanderLinde, Scary Wombat, Dawid Ferenczy, Unheilig, Ken Wayne. It is really upset to see so many persons are seeing this question as off topic. It's a programming question in Java. Since I'm new to Java programming I cannot the word question properly so it fits into the Website rules. I agree that this question may not be useful to other programmers because My idea in posting the question is to get correct running code for this program. If possible reframe the question and reopen it from Your end so it may be useful to other programmers. Thank You all for Your Time.

Comment: @ostrichofevil I have rewritten code as You said. I have attached in image file https://ibb.co/eGVn1F rewritten code and error. Kindly correct code and send Me running code. Thank You.

Comment: You have an extra closing brace at the end.

Comment: @ostrichofevil After removing extra brace code got compiled Successfully. But I'm not getting any result. I have coded to return result of addition but it is not returning. See My code statement: return x + y; it is not returning anything. Kindly tell me how to return the addition result inside the function. I have attached code http://ibb.co/cZTGBF. See it. Thank You.

Comment: @ostrichofevil Thank You for You reviewing My code and providing Me solution. Thank You for Your answers' for this question. This question is closed now as it does not comply Website requirements'. I'm little sad.

Comment: Thank You everyone for Your Time towards this question and Your efforts towards answers'.